# Convert interpolating function to a Bezier curve

Tags: graphics, interpolation, conversion, splines

I've been wondering, is there a way to convert an interpolation into a sequence of `BezierCurve` objects that form each step in the interpolation?

There is an easy way to plot an `InterpolatingFunction` as shown in [Easy way to plot ODE solutions from NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve):

```
ifn = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x]^3 == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
  y, {x, 0, 10}, Method -> "Extrapolation"];
ifn // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

But as can be seen, when a method takes large steps, the path plotted is not smooth.  This can be easily fixed with `ListLinePlot[ifn, InterpolationOrder -> 3]` or with `Plot[ifn[t], {t,...}]`.  So my question is perhaps academic.  However, both methods end up sampling the function at points between the steps.  It is a trivial objection, I know, since I'm pretty sure any curve (e.g. `Circle[]` as well as `BezierCurve[]`) is produced by connecting sample points.

Answer (score 8):

The function `hermiteToBezierPoints[]` computes the Bezier control points for `BezierCurve` from values of the function and its derivatives up to some order at each endpoint of an interval.
The function `ifnToBezierCurve[ifn]` passes the relevant data for an interpolating function `ifn` to `hermiteToBezierPoints[]` and wraps the results in `BezierCurve` or `JoinedCurve[BezierCurve[...],...]`.
I originally started down this line of development when I read this Q&A:
[Plot with NDSolve for a range of initial values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270395/plot-with-ndsolve-for-a-range-of-initial-values).
So the motivation was to plot `NDSolve` solutions via Bezier curves.

The function `ifnToBezierCurve[]` might convert any univariate scalar-valued `InterpolatingFunction`, although it complains about those that do not have `"Hermite"` as the `"InterpolationMethod"`.  I had to guess what `InterpolatingFunction` does when the function data at the end points is insufficient to determine an interpolant of degree `InterpolationOrder`.  These are the ones that can have kinks.  It uses data from adjacent points, but I had to guess exactly how.  So far it has worked on the random examples I threw at it. It handles ones that have [jump discontinuities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98349/4999) with a simple application of `Split[..., Unequal]` and [`` Internal`PartitionRagged ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions/83124#83124).

#### Examples

**OP's.**

```
ifn = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x]^3 == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
   y, {x, 0, 10}, Method -> "Extrapolation"];
Show[
 ListLinePlot[ifn, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4.6]],
 Graphics[{
   ColorData[97][2], AbsoluteThickness[2.6],
   ifnToBezierCurve[ifn]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

**`` Developer`PackedArrayForm `` of order 3**

```
ifnToBezierCurve[
  NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x]^3 == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
   y, {x, 0, 1}]] // Graphics
```

[image]

**Variable order, non-Hermite method.** Graphics output same as above.

```
ifnToBezierCurve[
  NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x]^3 == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
   y, {x, 0, 1}, InterpolationOrder -> All]] // Graphics
```

> ifnToBezierCurve::meth: Currently converting interpolations using interpolation method Local Taylor series are unimplemented; returning a BezierCurve based on Hermite method with SplineDegree -> 3.

You can override the warning by explicitly setting `SplineDegree`, which then creates Bezier curves of uniform degree from the interpolating function and its derivatives. (Graphics same as above.)

```
ifnToBezierCurve[
  NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x]^3 == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
   y, {x, 0, 1}, InterpolationOrder -> All], 
  SplineDegree -> 5] // Graphics
```

**Discontinuities**

Here's an ODE that has jumps:

```
Graphics[{
  ifnToBezierCurve[
   NDSolveValue[{y'[x] + y[x] == 
      2 DiracDelta[x - 1] + 2 DiracDelta[x - 2] + 2 DiracDelta[x - 3],
      y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 4}]]
  },
 PlotRange -> All,
 Options@Plot]
```

[image]

**Irregular, user-defined interpolation with kinks**

```
idata = {{{0}, 1, 2, -1}, {{1}, -1}, {{3/2}, 1}, {{2}, 3}, {{5/2}, 
    0}, {{3}, -1, 1, 2, -3, 1}};
foo = Interpolation[N@idata, InterpolationOrder -> 4];
Show[
 Plot[foo[t], {t, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5.6], 
  PlotRange -> All],
 Graphics[{ColorData[97][2], AbsoluteThickness[2.6],
   ifnToBezierCurve@foo
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

#### Code dump

```
(* Bezier pts from derivatives at x0, x1 *)
hermiteToBezierPoints // ClearAll;
hermiteToBezierPoints[{{x0_}, f0__}, {{x1_}, f1__}] := 
  hermiteToBezierPoints[{x0, x1}, {f0}, {f1}];
hermiteToBezierPoints[{x0_, x1_}, f0_?VectorQ, f1_?VectorQ] := 
  Module[
   {dx, order0, rng0, order1, rng1, n, yy0, yy1},
   dx = x1 - x0;
   order0 = Length@f0 - 1;
   rng0 = Range[0, order0];
   order1 = Length@f1 - 1;
   rng1 = Range[0, order1];
   n = order0 + order1 + 1;(* Bezier/Hermite order *)
   yy0 = f0*dx^rng0/Pochhammer[n + 1 - rng0, rng0];
   yy1 = f1*(-dx)^rng1/Pochhammer[n + 1 - rng1, rng1];
   Transpose@{
     Subdivide[x0, x1, n],
     Join[
      Outer[Binomial, rng0, rng0] . yy0,
      Outer[Binomial, rng1, rng1] . yy1 // Reverse]
     }
   ];

(*"
 * Single BezierCurve per segment alternative
"*)

(* unneeded as yet
(*bit field positions-inferred,perhaps mistaken*)
$bitFlagsPos=2;
$extrapBit=0;(*whether to warn about extrapolation*)
$rectArrayBit=1; (*whether the data (f,f',...) is a rectangular array \
(not ragged) *)
$machPrecBit=2; (*whether the data (f,f',...) is MachinePrecision *)
$repeatedBit=4;  (*whether repeated abscissae are permitted *)
*)

ifnGetData // ClearAll;
iIfnGetData // ClearAll;
(*** internal function ***)
iIfnGetData[
    if : Verbatim[InterpolatingFunction][_, type_, 
      coords_, {Developer`PackedArrayForm, split_, a_}, ___], 
    Automatic] /; if["InterpolationMethod"] === "Hermite"(*/;BitAnd[
  type[[$bitFlagsPos]],2^$rectArrayBit]>0*):=
  <|"Coordinates" -> coords,
   "FunctionData" -> 
    Internal`PartitionRagged[a, Differences@split]|>;
iIfnGetData[
    if : Verbatim[InterpolatingFunction][_, type_, coords_, 
      a : {__List}, ___], Automatic] /; 
   if["InterpolationMethod"] === "Hermite" :=
  <|"Coordinates" -> coords,
   "FunctionData" -> a|>;
(* non-Hermite *)
iIfnGetData[if_InterpolatingFunction, Automatic] /; 
   if["InterpolationMethod"] =!= "Hermite" := (
   Message[ifnToBezierCurve::meth, if["InterpolationMethod"], 
    First@if["InterpolationOrder"]];
   iIfnGetData[if, First@if["InterpolationOrder"]]);
(* non-Automatic SplineDegree *)
iIfnGetData[if_InterpolatingFunction, sdeg_Integer?Positive] :=
  (* SplineDegree deg will be effectively be odd *)
  With[{coords = if@"Coordinates",
    a = Transpose@
      Through[NestList[Derivative[1], if, Floor[sdeg/2]][
        "ValuesOnGrid"]]},
   <|"Coordinates" -> coords,
    "FunctionData" -> a|>
   ];
(*** UI function ***)
ifnGetData[if_InterpolatingFunction, sdeg_] :=
  Module[{data},
   data = iIfnGetData[if, sdeg];
   With[{coordsegs = Split[First@data@"Coordinates", Unequal]},
    {coordsegs, 
     Internal`PartitionRagged[data@"FunctionData", 
      Length /@ coordsegs]}
    ]];

ifnToBezierCurve // ClearAll;
ifnToBezierCurve::meth = 
  "Currently converting interpolations using interpolation method `` \
are unimplemented; returning a BezierCurve based on Hermite method \
with SplineDegree -> ``.";
(* If SplineDegree is not Automatic then Hermite interpolation model \
is used *)
ifnToBezierCurve // Options = {SplineDegree -> Automatic};
ifnToBezierCurve[ifn_InterpolatingFunction, OptionsPattern[]] /;
   Length@ifn@"Domain" == 1 && ifn@"OutputDimensions" === {} :=
  With[{data = ifnGetData[ifn, OptionValue@SplineDegree]},
   MapThread[
     Function[{t, x},(* time steps, function step data *)
      If[
       MatrixQ[x] && 
        2 Length@x[[1]] > First@ifn@"InterpolationOrder",
       (* all components the same sufficient degree *)
       With[{sd = 2 Length@x[[1]] - 1},(* SplineDegree *)
        BezierCurve[ (* composite BezierCurve *)
         Join[
          {{t[[1]], x[[1, 1]]}},
          Flatten[
           MapThread[
            Rest[hermiteToBezierPoints[##]] &,
            {Partition[t, 2, 1], Most[x], Rest[x]}
            ],
           1]
          ],
         SplineDegree -> sd]
        ],
       (* degrees of components vary or
        are less than InterpolatingOrder *)
       Module[{delayedRest, iorder, ncoeffs, i},
        delayedRest := (delayedRest = Rest; Identity);
        ncoeffs = Length /@ x;
        JoinedCurve@ (* joined BezierCurve pieces *)
         Table[
          iorder = ncoeffs[[j]] + ncoeffs[[j + 1]] - 1;
          i = 0;
          While[iorder < First@ifn@"InterpolationOrder",
           ++i;
           With[{dj = 3/4 - 1/4 (-1)^i (3 + 2 i)},
            If[1 <= j + dj <= Length@x,
             iorder += ncoeffs[[j + dj]]
             ]]
           ];
          With[{bpts = hermiteToBezierPoints[
              {t[[j]], t[[j + 1]]},
              x[[j]],
              Join[
               x[[j + 1]],
               Table[Derivative[k][ifn][t[[j + 1]]],
                {k, ncoeffs[[j + 1]], iorder - ncoeffs[[j]]}]]
              ]},
           BezierCurve[delayedRest@bpts, 
            SplineDegree -> Length[bpts] - 1]
           ],
          {j, Length@t - 1}
          ]]
       ] (* end If[] *)
      ],
     data
     ] /; FreeQ[data, ifnGetData]
   ];
```